# Xcode 6.1 issues while opening the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I have recently started working on IOS app development and was encountering an issue. I have downloaded XCode 6.1.1 and my target SDK is IOS 8.1.

On building and running my application I dont have the mobile/Iphone interface coming up in which I can check my layout how the app will be presented once it is deployed on Iphone. All I get is a rectangular box which is definitely not resizable and I am unable to check my app.

On this rectangular box which is definitely not the one I am expecting, I can see my labels and buttons in a crap state. 
I tried changing the SDK version to 7.1, changed the build type from debug to release, change the deployment target to 7.1 also, using Iphone 5S,7.1 simulator also but the issue seems non-resolved.

[image]

Comment: Please show screenshot what you are facing. Your app should run in ios8 simulators.

Comment: I am unable to post any images as it requires a minimum reputation of 10 to do it. Please give me your email id so that I can mail it across to you. Need a fixture asap.

Comment: Upload somewhere and add a link to the Q

Comment: Here's the link to the image: http://postimg.org/image/92upamdqj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're on 100% zoom, so you should be able to see the full phone by zooming out. In the iOS simulator, in the top bar go to Window->Scale and select 50% or 75%. If the zoom level is the problem, that should fix it. Hope it helps :)